# How do I re-use expressions in Cucumber?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have this scenario where I want to check if a banner element exists on each page.

I have created a separate `banners.js` file that contains the (Selenium Webdriver) Javascript that does the check:

*./components/banner.js*

```
const { By } = require('selenium-webdriver');

async function checkBannerExists(webdriver, bannerClass) {
    var banner = await webdriver.driver.findElement(By.className(bannerClass)).getRect();
    return banner.height;
  };

module.exports = { checkBannerExists };
```

And I can simply call it in a step's file expression when I need it:

```
const banners = require("../../components/banners");

Given('I am on the home page',  async function () {
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();
    
    this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('h1')));
    await this.driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com');
});

Then('there should be a banner', async function() {
    var homeBanner = await banners.checkBannerExists(this, 'banner');
    assert.ok(homeBanner!==null);
});
```

All good there.

But if I add this same expression to another page, eg:

```
const banners = require("../../components/banners");

Given('I am on the about us page',  async function () {
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();
    
    this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('h1')));
    await this.driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com/about');
});

Then('there should be a banner', async function() {
    var homeBanner = await banners.checkBannerExists(this, 'banner');
    assert.ok(homeBanner!==null);
});
```

I get the error `Multiple step definitions match:`

Is there a way I can re-use the same expression across multiple steps and features files?

Comment: Did you read the documentation https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/world.md

Comment: Thanks @M.P.Korstanje, I did see that. Maybe I'm don't fully understand it, but it seems the Gherkin script is different as it is sending 2 different variables - `Given my color is "blue"` and `Given my color is "red"`. I'm not sending any variables with my Gherkin script.

Comment: Then you don't need the same step definition twice. They're global in scope. You will have to share the browser between your step definitions which you can do with  the world object.

Comment: Ok, but where should I place the step definition and how do I reference it within my 2 .js step files?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a different approach to this using `Scenario Outline` where you use the same `.feature` file and give it multiple pages:

*genericBannerTest.feature*

```
Feature: Generic Banner Tests
 
    Scenario Outline: Run a check for generic banner
        Given I am on the '<page>' page
        Then there should be a banner on the '<page>' page

    Examples: 
        | page     |
        | /        |
        | /contact |
        | /about   |
        | /products|
```

*genericBannerTestSteps.js*

```
const banners = require("../components/banners");
// other required stuff

Given('I am on the {string} page', async function (string) {
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();
    
    this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('h1')));
    await this.driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com' + string);
});

Then('there should be a banner on the {string} page', async function(string) {
  let bannerClass = 'banner-module'
  if (string == '/') {
    bannerClass = 'home-banner';
  }
  else if (string == '/product-banner') {
    bannerClass = 'prod-short';
  }

  var banner = await banners.checkBannerExists(this, bannerClass);
  assert.ok(banner!==null);
});
```

*banner.js*

```
const { By } = require('selenium-webdriver');

async function checkBannerExists(webdriver, bannerClass) {
  var banner = await webdriver.driver.findElement(By.className(bannerClass)).getRect();
  return banner.height;
};

module.exports = { checkBannerExists };
```